# Merge two arrays into one

Tags: php, json, fusioncharts

I know there is suck thing in stack overflow, but, all of the different case with my case, different structure of array, and I can not implement in my case.

I have two arrays.

First:

```
  Array
    (
        [seriesname] => rencana
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 70
                    )

                [xxx] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => xxx
                    )
            )
    )
```

And second:

```
Array
(
    [seriesname] => realisasi
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 20
                )
            [xxx] => Array
                (
                        [value] => xxx
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried `array_merge($first,$second);` , and seriesname has gone in returned array. `array_push($first,$second);` returns nothing.

What function or what am I missing?

Thanks.

By the way here we go the goal that I want to achieve:

result

```
array (
[seriesname] => rencana
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 70
                )

            [xxx] => Array
                (
                   [value] => xxx
                )

        ),
[seriesname] => realisasi
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 20
                )

            [xxx] => Array
                (
                    [value] => xxx
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: You cant have same key in same level.

Comment: you cant do this. AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the in one array -

```
$new = array($first,$second);
```

Comment: dam, to much stress so cannot thing the way you think, thanks alot dude